# postgresql:Can't use query methods that take a query string on a prepared statement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to create a java application that inserts into `postgresql`database.
This is my code

```
import java .sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;

public class insert {
   public static void main(String args[])
 {

      try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         Connection c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
            "postgres", "saurabh");
         c.setAutoCommit(false);
         System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the no.of records you want to enter");
         int n = input.nextInt();
         for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++)
{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )";
         PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement(sql);
         System.out.println("Enter id");
         int id= input.nextInt();
         pst.setInt(1, id);
         System.out.println("Enter name");
         String name = input.nextLine();
         pst.setString(2, name);
         System.out.println("Enter Address");
         String address = input.nextLine();
         pst.setString(3, address);
         System.out.println("Enter Salary");
         double salary = input.nextDouble();
         pst.setDouble(4, salary);
         pst.executeUpdate();
         pst.close();
}


         c.commit();
         c.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Records created successfully");
   }
}
```

When I execute this, i get an error 
`can't use query methods that take a query string on a prepared statement`.

Can anybody suggest why the error is generated?

Comment: You have 5 columns in your insert clause, but you're giving only 4 parameters.

Comment: The exception indicates that you call `executeUpdate(sql)` instead of `executeUpdate()` (or `execute`, `execute`) on a `PreparedStatement`. Are you sure this code causes the exception? You might want to include the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're asking about is the your query has five columns and you only provide 4 bind values with

```
(ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )
```

you skipped `age` below. Also, you need to consume the trailing newlines left by `nextInt`. And, one benefit of using a `PreparedStatement` is the possibility of batching. I would also add a `finally` block to `close` your resources. Something like,

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb", "postgres",
            "saurabh");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no.of records you want to enter");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) "
            + "VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter id");
        int id = input.nextInt();
        pst.setInt(1, id);
        input.nextLine(); // <-- consume trailing newline.

        System.out.println("Enter name");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        pst.setString(2, name);
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        int age = input.nextInt();
        pst.setInt(3, age);
        input.nextLine(); // <-- consume trailing newline
        System.out.println("Enter Address");
        String address = input.nextLine();
        pst.setString(4, address);
        System.out.println("Enter Salary");
        double salary = input.nextDouble();
        pst.setDouble(5, salary);
        pst.addBatch();
    }
    pst.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
} finally {
    if (pst != null) {
        try {
            pst.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Records created successfully");
```

Comment: it throws an exception " BATCH ENTRY ABORTED". Call getNextException to see the cause         Please Help